# My iPad can't connect to Sony Camera wifi under "Movie" mode

Tags: sony-camera-api

I purchased Sony Camera DSC-HX60 and I'm going to build iPad app which controls sony camera using Sony Camera Remote API.

And I could check the Sony Camera wifi connection from iPad on common mode of camera. So the connection from iPad to Camera would be fine.

But for now, I am going to control the camera video recording from iPad using "setmovierec" api.
So according to manual guide, I setup the camera mode to "Movie".
However the camera is saying "Unavailable in this shooting mode. Switch to another mode"

I would be appreciated if someone helps me fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have updated the "Smart Remote" application on the *camera*, the inbuilt one is outdated/has problems.
Simon.